# `delete()` vs. `fetch()` with underspecified relative restrictions

Tags: datajoint

My database has a number of sessions.

```py
@schema
class Session(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Subject
    session_datetime: datetime
    """
```

I could fetch or delete them as follows.

```py
total_sessions = session.Session # N=4
total_sessions.fetch()   # Successful output
total_session.delete()   # Successful cascading delete prompt
```

If I'm only interested in sessions after a given year/month, I can generate a query with a relative restriction, fully specifying `datetime`.

```py
later_sessions1 = (session.Session & 'session_datetime > "2021-06-01 12:00:00"') # N=2
later_sessions1.fetch()   # Successful output
later_sessions1.delete()  # Successful cascading delete prompt
```

If I don't fully specify `datetime`, I can still fetch the data, but deletion fails.

```py
later_sessions2 = (session.Session & 'session_datetime > "2021-06"') # N=2
later_sessions2.fetch()   # Successful output
later_sessions2.delete()  # OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2021-06' for column 'session_datetime' at row 1")
```

Is this intended? Should `fetch()` and `delete()` fail under the same conditions?

---

EDIT: calling `make_sql()` on `later_sessions2` returns the following

```
'SELECT DISTINCT `subject`,`session_datetime` FROM `test_session`.`session` WHERE(session_datetime > "2021-06")'
```

If called on the fully specified `later_sessions1`, the last `WHERE` component includes the full datetime.

Comment: Interesting. That doesn't seem expected but curious what is the output of `later_sessions.make_sql()`.

Comment: Edited to include the `make_sql()`, and differentiate `later_sessions` 1 and 2.

Comment: This seems like a quirk of MySQL rather than DataJoint. Can you reproduce this in  SQL directly?

Comment: Right, what happens if you try as Dimitri is suggesting: `DELETE FROM \`test_session\`.\`session\` WHERE session_datetime > '2021-06'`

Comment: To run this directly with DataJoint you can do: `dj.conn().query("DELETE FROM \`test_session\`.\`session\` WHERE session_datetime > '2021-06'").fetchall()`

Comment: With the datetime fully specified, I get an `IntegrityError: Cannot delete or update a parent row`. With `2021-06` alone, I get the same `OperationalError: (1292`, so yes, it does seem to be a quirk of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Per comment thread above with Raphael and Dimitri, this is a quirk of MySQL rather than DataJoint